# Getting average from passed subjects in structure

Tags: c++, data-structures

I enter info about the student first name lastname index number and degree for each subject.If the degree is over 5 the subject is passed and i get average from passed subjects.If i print the function like `printf("%f",P.averagefunc())` the number is ok but i when i try to get the average to variable like `float average=P.averagefunc();` inside struct student or `float average=averagefunc();` inside struct subject and i print the result i get some weird number like -888266.00000.Any help how i can get the float function to float variable?
Please dont downvote the question i am new to this and i tried to explain my problem as best as i could.

```
struct subject{
int programming;
int electronics;
int calculus1;
int english;
int usersoftware;

float averagefunc()
{
    int sum=0;
    int passed=0;
    if(programming>5)
    {
        sum+=programming;
        passed++;
    }
    if(electronics>5)
    {
        sum+=electronics;
        passed++;
    }
    if(calculus1>5)
    {
        sum+=calculus1;
        passed++;
    }
    if(english>5)
    {
        sum+=english;
        passed++;
    }
    if(usersoftware>5)
    {
        sum+=usersoftware;
        passed++;
    }
    return (float)suma/(float)polozeni;
}

};

struct student{
char firstname[10];
char lastname[15];
int indexnumber;
struct subject P;
};
```

Comment: You are showing bogus code to us, that doesn't even compile.

Comment: http://cpp.sh/5a7u here is the code copy it and compile it i dont think shell will run it

Comment: Here it doesn't compile, e.g.: `return (float)suma/(float)polozeni;`

Comment: `return (float)sum/(float)passed` mistake in my translation of code it is in my native language sry

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] in your question please.

Comment: Use `std::cout` for printing rather than `printf`.  The `printf` may require conversions before passing values.

Comment: Change your `student` structure to use `std::string` and prefer to not use character arrays unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Since you are programming in C++ **and not C**, prefer to use structure names only when declaring variables, such as `subject P;`.

Comment: Since your posted code doesn't compile and I *can't use my debugger*, please do me a favor and use your debugger to execute each statement one at a time.  Watch the values of variables.  Find out which statement is causing the issue.